# reCaptcha not working on webform

Tags: webforms, captcha

I am using a Webform module to create a form to which I would like to add recaptcha. I've gone through the readme files for both captcha and recaptcha modules and all the configuration settings look fine.

The only thing I am unsure about is on admin/config/people/captcha general settings page.... I am trying to add a new form id to reflect my webform (webform-client-form-25) but it won't accept it. It says "Illegal form_id".

I've got the public and private keys set.

Skip CAPTCHA is NOT selected for any role.

From the view source:

How do I get the recaptcha working for my webform?

Comment: try using webform_client_form_25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since people may not check the comments for the answer:

Yaazkal suggested in comments try using webform_client_form_25

Hyphens(-) are generally translated into underscores(_) for machine names in drupal.

Comment: Not that it's hard to translate hyphens to underscores, but you can directly see the form ID in your webform's html source e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="webform_client_form_25" />` Also note for google reCaptcha there is sometimes a delay before the captcha will start showing up on your form.